# Why this linux module code not pressing keys?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to make module that simulate press keys.
Why this linux module code not pressing keys?

```
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/device.h>
#include<linux/timer.h>
#include<linux/kdev_t.h>
#include<linux/jiffies.h>
#include<linux/input.h>
#include<asm/io.h>

static struct input_dev *key_dev;

static int hellopress_init(void)
{
    key_dev = input_allocate_device();

    set_bit(EV_KEY,key_dev->evbit);

    set_bit(KEY_A,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_B,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_C,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_D,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_E,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_F,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_G,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_H,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_I,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_J,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_K,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_L,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_M,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_N,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_O,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_P,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_Q,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_R,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_S,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_T,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_U,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_V,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_W,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_X,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_Y,key_dev->keybit);
    set_bit(KEY_Z,key_dev->keybit);

    input_register_device(key_dev);

    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_A, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_A, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_B, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_B, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_C, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_C, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_D, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_D, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_E, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_E, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_F, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_F, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_G, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_G, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_H, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_H, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_I, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_I, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_J, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_J, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_K, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_K, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_L, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_L, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_M, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_M, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_N, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_N, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_O, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_O, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_P, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_P, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_Q, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_Q, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_R, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_R, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_S, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_S, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_T, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_T, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_U, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_U, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_V, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_V, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_W, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_W, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_X, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_X, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_Y, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_Y, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_Z, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, KEY_Z, 0);

    input_report_key(key_dev, 30, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, 30, 0);
    input_report_key(key_dev, 76, 1);
    input_report_key(key_dev, 76, 0);


    input_sync(key_dev);

    printk(KERN_INFO "Device Driverz Insert...Done!!!\n");

    return 0;
}

static void hellopress_exit(void)
{
    input_unregister_device(key_dev);

    printk(KERN_INFO "Device Driver unloaded...Done!!!\n");
}


module_init(hellopress_init);
module_exit(hellopress_exit);

MODULE_AUTHOR("Vic");
MODULE_VERSION("0.1.2");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

It compiles and run without errors, but no key press. Only one suspicious  message:

> [ 1275.986167] input: Unspecified device as /devices/virtual/input/input19

> [ 1275.986622] Device Driverz Insert...Done!!!

What I made wrong? And how to make keypress from kernel module?

I want to simulate key presses as it was done by the real keyboard.

Comment: Your instantiation of the input device is half-baked you need to describe and register the device (no guarantee that anything in user space will listen to it, though), and it's unclear if you want to have your own virtual keyboard device or you want to simulate key presses as it was done by the real (connected to the computer) keyboard?

Comment: to simulate key presses as it was done by the real  keyboard.

Comment: I suspect it is because you are doing the keypresses in the init routine, before the udev event which would notify listeners that a new input device is ready.  Try moving the keypress to a write call, then `echo foo >/dev/inputX`